# How to archive a whole database?

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql-server-2014, archive

I have a database that is not going to be used anymore but that needs to be kept around for a long time. I'd like to remove it from the production system. My goal is to save storage space when archiving that database. I need to preserve it at full fidelity, so a BCP export is not good enough. I also would not trust generated SQL scripts to preserve it fully.

Two options:

1. Take an uncompressed backup and compress it using 7-Zip.
2. Detach the database and compress the MDF and LDF files using 7-Zip.

Is option 2 safe? Which one is preferable? What are important considerations here?

Comment: No, do not go route #2. Take a backup and after taking the backup, verify it. When you detach, you don't know whether the database was corrupt at that point in time. If it was, you may be toast attempting to re-attach it

Comment: Don't use detach. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-file-backups/ Also if you're on standard or better, use the native backup compression - I suspect you won't find a huge gain from 7-Zip on top of that (at least not commensurate with the additions time taken to compress/decompress).

Comment: @AaronBertrand the native backup compression is a super fast algorithm with small window. It is significantly worse than the state-of-the-art 7-Zip. 2x over native compression is typical. (The speed is like 50x worse).

Comment: Okay, still, my main point was: STOP thinking a detach is a backup. IT'S NOT.

Comment: Why is performance an issue?  You are doing a one-time maintenance activity.  If the 3rd party compression corrupts your backup file for whatever reason, MSFT support cannot help you.

Comment: @Greg I can assure you that space usage *is* an issue (I assume you mean space by "performance"). I will store multiple copies of the archived data. This is required to prevent bit rot, no matter which of the methods given above I use.

Comment: i misunderstood then, i thought speed being 50x worse was an issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can save the index creation DDL statement and delete the indexes, to save more space before any archival path you choose. There's more advice on shrinking and fill factor here: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/02/how-to-really-compress-your-sql-server-backups/

I've used option 2 to get better results than with the SQL built-in backup compression. Always start with DBCC CHECKDB ! Also take into consideration that your restore time will go up if you go on this path, as it takes a while to (de)compress with 7-Zip's best compression settings.

Answer (score 1):

To be sure you have a backup you can restore and use directly I would:

1. Take a native full backup with options Verify backup when finished
   and Perform checksum before writing to media and Compress backup
2. Test the backup; restore to test instance and perform DBCC CHECKDB

Comment: Which option is better though? I do understand that I can take a backup.

Comment: @usr I think you got enough confirmation in the comments about which solution is better.